# Mysql - Possible solutions for "group by group_concat()"?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Is it possible to group the result by the result of an aggregate function without nesting the result on it self ?

```
"SELECT b.pizza, GROUP_CONCAT(t.topping_names SEPARATOR ',') AS topping_string FROM bascket AS b
LEFT JOIN toppings AS t ON t.pizza = b.pizza 
 GROUP BY pizza, topping_string "
```

The above query should return all the pizzas grouped by their selected topping_string (should return unique pizza+toppings) . But ofcourse that is not valid because the group_concat is done after the grouping. So the only alternative i see would be to wrap that query and make it a subquery of the actual grouping :

```
SELECT sub.* FROM (  
SELECT b.pizza, GROUP_CONCAT(t.topping_names SEPARATOR ',') AS topping_string FROM bascket AS b
    LEFT JOIN toppings AS t ON t.pizza = b.pizza  
) AS sub  
GROUP BY sub.pizza, sub.topping_string
```

Is this a proper way to do it? Is there another alternative ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is the proper way to do it if you are doing two aggregations, there is no alternative to performing the first aggregation in a subquery.

However, you don't have any aggregations so you can enforce uniqueness by using `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT 
        b.pizza, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(t.topping_names SEPARATOR ',') AS topping_string
FROM    bascket AS b
    LEFT JOIN toppings AS t 
        ON t.pizza = b.pizza
GROUP BY b.pizza;
```

N.B. If you did need to perform an aggregation you are missing a group by in your subquery, should be:

```
SELECT sub.*, COUNT(*) AS Quantity FROM (  
SELECT b.pizza, GROUP_CONCAT(t.topping_names SEPARATOR ',') AS topping_string 
FROM bascket AS b
    LEFT JOIN toppings AS t ON t.pizza = b.pizza  
GROUP BY b.pizza
) AS sub  
GROUP BY sub.pizza, sub.topping_string
```

Comment: The actual query is alot bigger, that was just a simple example of the underlieng problem . So i see that there can't be a grouping based on the grouping result on the same query . I will accept your answer

Comment: Yes i notices the group by in the subquery . Ty again for the help .